# .Net Core SignalR: Send to Users except caller from IHubContext (injected into controller)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-signalr

in order to identify the current user only when working with an injected IHubContext in a controller, I am storing a group with the user id.
However, I'm struggling to send to everyone else since I cannot figure out a way to find out which connection ID to exclude.

My Hub

```
public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
{

    Groups.AddAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);  
    return base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

In my controller method, I can invoke methods for that user:

```
await _signalRHub.Clients.Group(User.Identity.Name).InvokeAsync("Send", User.Identity.Name + ": Message for you");
```

IHubContext.Clients.AllExcept requires a list of connection IDs. How can I obtain the connection ID for the identified user in order to only notify others?

Comment: Why you make this inside the controller? Why not a method on the hub which the client can execute on server like? There you have your connectionId

Comment: The Controller notifies clients of new appointment objects - they're displaying a calendar, and if a user adds something to the calendar and the batch method succeeds, I would like to push the changes made in the dbContext to all other users in JSON

Comment: How long does you batch method works? I normaly use the scenario that the mastermodel is on the server. So if the adding of this element is very short on the server you can also send to the caller client. This is only an option if your batch job is fast enough. Think about if the adding has en error. In this case you also do not like that you have the new calendar item on the callerclient.

Comment: Later there will be a method OthersInGroup. But it's not ready at the moment

Comment: The batch method already pushes the changes back to the caller - this cannot be changed in the component. It also notifies the client via signalr of anything going wrong, I'm pushing an object to PNotify for this. However, I'd like to notify anyone else that there is new data - it would be annoying if that also went to the guy who's already got the data...

Comment: Can you just de-dupe on the client? Might be easier...

Comment: I'll probably have to do that, yes - a Clients.Others method would be easier though. I've checked through the issues on Github and they're trying to implement sth like this, not yet for the context though. So far this is only possible from the Hub itself, where the connection id is available from the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Pawel, I am now de-duping on the client, which works (well, as long as all your clients are authenticated).

```
private async Task Identification() => await Clients.Group(Context.User.Identity.Name).InvokeAsync("Identification", Context.User.Identity.Name);
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{    
    await Groups.AddAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);            
    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    await Identification();
}
```

The JS to go along with it (abbreviated):

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnection("/theHub");            
var myIdentification;
connection.on("Identification", userId => {
    myIdentification = userId;
});
```

Now you can test for `callerIdentification == myIdentification` in addtional methods like `connection.on("something", callerIdentification)`

@Tester's comment makes me hopeful there'll be a better way at some point when sending through IHubContext.

Answer (score 1):

In SignalR core, the connectionId is stored in the signalR connection. Assuming you have a signalrR connection defined as follows

```
signalrConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl('/api/apphub')
...
.build();
```

Whenever you make a fetch request, add the signalR connectionId as a header. Eg.

```
        response = await fetch(url, {
        ...
        headers: {
            'x-signalr-connection': signalrConnection.connectionId,
        },
    });
```

Then in your controller or wherever you have access to a httpContextAccessor, you can use the following to exclude the connection referenced in the header:

```
    public async Task NotifyUnitSubscribersExceptCaller()
{
    //Grab callers connectionId
    var connectionId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Headers["x-signalr-connection"] ?? "";
    await _hub.Clients.GroupExcept("myGroup", connectionId).SendCoreAsync("Sample", new object[] { "Hello World!" });
}
```