# Connection ID when calling SignalR Core Hub method from Controller

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

This is a follow-up to [another question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46904678).  What's the effect of calling `HubContext.Clients.Caller` or `HubContext.Clients.Others` from the controller?  I see it depends on the [connection ID](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/e39d453a8238c222f400fd081060c6b506291275/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core/HubCallerClients.cs#L10).  What value would it have in this situation?

If the connection ID (and thus `Caller` and `Others`) is invalid then (from within the controller action) how could I obtain a connection ID (for the client currently calling the Web API) that I could use with `HubContext.Clients`'s methods?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> What's the effect of calling `HubContext.Clients.Caller` or `HubContext.Clients.Others` from the controller? I see it depends on the connection ID. What value would it have in this situation?

There is neither `.Caller` nor `.Others` on `HubContext.Clients` (of type [`HubClients<THub>`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d4fccce53568aa479b56a9e69c069abeab51b346/src/SignalR/server/Core/src/Internal/HubClients.cs)).

"*It's not possible to access those from `IHubContext`. `Caller` and `Others` both depend on knowing which client is the caller. When you're in IHubContext, we don't know and there may not even **be** a current caller since you could be in an MVC controller action, etc.*"
— [aspnet/SignalR#2274 (comment)](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2274#issuecomment-389013456)

> (from within the controller action) how could I obtain a connection ID (for the client currently calling the Web API) that I could use with `HubContext.Clients`'s methods?

"*there is no way of knowing who the current caller is from the IHubContext*"
— [aspnet/SignalR#2274 (comment)](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2274#issuecomment-389202646)

## Using Groups and Users may be a solution

"*If you have access to the User ID of the user who initiated the action, you can use `.Users(userId)` to send a message to all of that user's connections. Similarly, you add the SignalR connections to a group and send to that group using `.Group(groupName)`*"
— [aspnet/SignalR#2274 (comment)](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2274#issuecomment-389227033)

## Pass the connection ID from the client side

As of [@microsoft/signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr) 3.0.0, `connectionId` is available on `HubConnection`:

```js
controller.doStuff(hubConnection.connectionId);
```

Outdated answer written at the time of [@aspnet/signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr) 1.0.0-rc1-update1:

> You can get the connection ID on the client that calls the API, and then send it to the controller.
>
> Hub:
>
> ```cs
> public string GetConnectionId()
> {
>     return Context.ConnectionId;
> }
> ```
>
> Client:
>
> ```js
> connection.invoke('getConnectionId')
>     .then(function (connectionId) {
>         // Send the connectionId to controller
>         controller.doStuff(connectionId);
>     });
> ```

Comment: Thanks.  Wow, that Github issue was just recently opened.  Looks like the simplest solution in my scenario may be to turn the initial WebAPI call into a hub method.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/72849496/5683904 for a working sample of sending the connectionId as a request header