# How to use websockets in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, server, client

im trying to develop a game where i store a scoreboard in a text file which is stored on server (currently on localhost). I am using http get and post calls in order to communicate with the server and get and send the data that i want. Now i want to implement websockets in order to send a notification from the server to the c# client. The notification will just display on the console a message for the user, for example in mu case i want to display a message to the user each time a user is added to the scoreboard, each time the UpdateScoreBoard method is called. Based on tutorials i found online i have managed to build the following code, can anyone make it more clear for me how the i will build the websocket for the server and how i will initialize the websocket on the client? Thank you

Startup.cs (Server)

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
        {
          //deleted code

            var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions()
            {
                KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
                ReceiveBufferSize = 4 * 1024
            };


            app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
        
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path == "/ws")
                {
                    if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                    {
                        WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                        await Echo(context, webSocket);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await next();
                }

            });
        }

        private async Task Echo(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
            {
                await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);

                result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            }
            await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

HttpClass.cs (Client) - where i call the http post request

```
public async override Task<List<Scoreboard>> UpdateScoreBoards(string username, int attempts, int seconds, DateTime date)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                //Creating a new instance of object Scoreboard
                //deleted code

                var url = "http://localhost:5000/api/Scoreboard";

                var socket_url = new Uri("ws://localhost:5000"); 
                var exitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                using (var client = new WebsocketClient(socket_url))
                {
                    client.ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                    client.ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info =>
                        Log.Information($"Reconnection happened, type: {info.Type}"));

                    client.MessageReceived.Subscribe(msg => Log.Information($"Message received: {msg}"));
                    await client.Start();

                    await Task.Run(() => client.Send("test"));

                    exitEvent.WaitOne();
                }

// deleted code
            }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> can anyone make it more clear for me how the i will build the websocket for the server and how i will initialize the websocket on the client?

As the example that you referenced demonstrated, making use of WebSocket in ASP.NET Core, we can add the [WebSockets middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.websocketmiddlewareextensions.usewebsockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_WebSocketMiddlewareExtensions_UseWebSockets_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_IApplicationBuilder_) in the `Configure` method, then add/configure request delegate to check and handle incoming WebSocket requests.

And after transitioned a request to a WebSocket connection with `AcceptWebSocketAsync()` method, we can use the returned WebSocket object to send and receive messages.

In `Echo` method, we can also perform custom code logic to generate and send reply message/notification based on received message(s).

```
//received message
var mes = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);

//code logic here
//...

//create reply message
var reply_mes = $"You sent {mes}.";

byte[] reply_mes_buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reply_mes);

await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(reply_mes_buffer, 0, reply_mes.Length), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
```

Besides, ASP.NET Core SignalR is an open-source library that simplifies implementing real-time communication functionality. And it does support WebSockets transport and we can easily achieving push messages/notifications to all connected clients or specified subsets of connected clients.

For more information about ASP.NET Core SignalR, you can check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 8):

The only thing you need in your `Startup` is to add the `UseWebsockets` middleware.
Then you can define your own middleware and filter connections if they are `websocket` type like below:

**Startup**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
            app.UseWebSockets();
            app.UseMiddleware<SocketWare>();
        }
```

**Middleware**

```
public class SocketWare {
        private RequestDelegate next;
        public SocketWare(RequestDelegate _next) {
            this.next = _next;
        }
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
            if (!context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest) {
                return;
            }
            var socket=await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
            await RunAsync(socket);
        }
        private async Task RunAsync(WebSocket socket) {
            try {
                var client = new ChatClient(socket);
                await client.RunAsync();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                throw;
            }
            
        }
        

    }
```

In my middleware i prefer to keep my business logic in a separate class that gets the `Websocket` injected in it like below:

**Client**

```
public class ChatClient
{
   private Task writeTask;
   private Task readTask;
   private WebSocket socket;
   private CancellationTokenSource cts=new CancellationTokenSource();
   ChatClient(WebSocket socket)
   {
       this.socket=socket;
   }
   public async Task RunAsync()
   {
      this.readTask=Task.Run(async ()=>await ReadLoopAsync(cts.Token),cts.Token);
      this.writeTask=Task.Run(async()=>await WriteLoopAsync(cts.Token),cts.Token);
      await Task.WhenAny(this.readTask,this.writeTask);
   }
   public async Task WriteLoopAsync()
   {
       Memory<byte> buffer=ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(1024);
       try {
           while (true) {
              var result= await this.socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer,....);
              var usefulBuffer=buffer.Slice(0,result.Count).ToArray();
              var raw=Encoding.Utf8.GetString(usefulBuffer);
              //deserialize it to whatever you need
              //handle message as you please (store it somwhere whatever)
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

               //socket error handling
               //break loop or continue with go to
        }
   }
   public async Task ReadLoopAsync()
   {
          try {
            while (true) {
              
                var data = await this.[someMessageProvider].GetMessageAsync() //read below !!!
                var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                //send the message on the websocket
                await this.socket.SendAsync(data, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            //do incorrect message/socket disconnect logic
        }
   }
}
```

Now regarding producing messages and consuming them. In your case you could define your producers as  some `Controller` routes like below .You would hit a route , produce a message and publish it to some message broker. I would use a Message Queue (RabbitMQ) or even a `Redis Pub/Sub` as a message bus.
You would publish messages from your `route`(s) and then consume them in your `ReadLoopAsync` method from `WebSocketClient` (look above).

**Producing messages**

```
public UpdateController:Controller
{
   private IConnection
   [HttpPost]
   [someroute]
   public void UpdateScoreboard(string someMessage)
   {
       this.connection.Publish("someChannel",someMessage);
   }
   [HttpPost]
   [someotherroute]
   public void DeletePlayer(string someOtherMessage)
   {
       this.connection.Publish("someChannel",someMessage);
   }
}
```

- **Redis pub/sub**
   Check redis pub/sub [here](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub)
   Also check my repository
  on github [here](https://github.com/sanzor/Ctesiphon) in which i am
  using exactly what you need (websockets, redis,pub sub)
- **RabbitMq**
   Another option as a message bus is to use `RabbitMQ` , for more info regarding C#   `API`
  [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html)
- **In Memory**

  You could also avoid using a third party and use some in memory data
  structure like a `BlockingCollection`.You could inject it as a
  `Singleton` service both in your `Controller(s)` and your socket
  `Middleware(s)`