# How can I send the message to a specific user using the user's email address stored in db?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a project in ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC SignalR. When I started the project I did not select Individual Account options in authorization. I want to send the message using the user's email address stored in a database instead of the connection Id but I can't achieve this. How can I fix this problem?

This is my hub class code:

```
 public class SignalRChat:Hub
    {
        
        Context c = new Context();
        public async Task setUserEmail(string email)
        {
            string id = Context.ConnectionId;
            c.EmailConnectionIds.Where(a => a.connection_id == id).FirstOrDefault().email = email;
        }
        
        public async Task ClientSendMessage(string connectionId,string user, string message)
        {
           var deger= c.EmailConnectionIds.Where(a => a.connection_id ==
            connectionId).FirstOrDefault();
            

            await Clients.Client(deger.connection_id).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage",user, message);
        }


        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {

            EmailConnectionId val = new EmailConnectionId();
            val.connection_id = Context.ConnectionId; ;
            val.email = "";
           
            c.EmailConnectionIds.Add(val);
            c.SaveChanges();

           await  base.OnConnectedAsync();


        }
        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            var connection = c.EmailConnectionIds.Where(a => a.connection_id ==
            Context.ConnectionId).FirstOrDefault();

            if (connection != null)
            {
                c.EmailConnectionIds.Remove(connection);
            }

            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

    }
```

This is my code:

```js
"use strict";

$(document).ready(() => {
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chathub").build();
  

     var email = $("#client").val();
  
    connection.start().then(() => connection.invoke('setUserEmail ', email));

    $("#msg-send").click(() => {
        let message = $("#txtMessage").val();
        $("#txtMessage").val(" ");
        var user = $("#sender").val();
        connection.invoke("ClientSendMessage", $("#client").val(), user, message)
            .catch(error => console.log("Error." + error));       
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.textContent = message;
        
        document.getElementById("chat-cont").appendChild(div);
    });

    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
        var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
        var encodedMsg =  msg;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.textContent = encodedMsg;
        
        document.getElementById("chat-cont").appendChild(div);
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="chat-cont" class="clearfix" style="max-height:450px;overflow:scroll;">
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:470px;margin-left:40%;bottom:50px !important;" class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="row">
            <h5>Connection ID : <span id="connectionId"></span></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7"><input type="text" id="sender" value="@ViewBag.message"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7"><input type="text" placeholder="ReceiverId" id="client"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7" style="position:relative;"> <input type="text" id="txtMessage" class="form-control" style="width:70%;"></div>
            <div class="col-md-5" style="position:absolute;margin-left:40%;"> <button id="msg-send" class="btn btn-success">Send</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure for 2.1, but maybe this can help: [How to use web sockets in C# .NET Core 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756390/how-to-use-web-sockets-in-c-sharp-net-core-3-1)

Comment: You can add each user to group with the group name being the email address. Then you send a message to the user in the group based on that email address

Comment: @Vince I tried it it works in identiry not my project , how can I select receiver email  stored in db and sen him the message

Comment: @Cankan https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a list of current connections `CurrentConnections`

```
static HashSet<EmailConnectionID> CurrentConnections = new HashSet<EmailConnectionID>();
class EmailConnectionID
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string connection_id { get; set; }
}
```

add the entries to CurrentConnections `OnConnectedAsync`

```
public override async Task<Task> OnConnectedAsync()
{

EmailConnectionID val = new EmailConnectionID();
val.connection_id = Context.ConnectionId; ;
val.email = "";
CurrentConnections.Add(val);

return base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

then after the client connect first thing you do is to send the email to the `hub` and edit the entry on the CurrentConnections list with the email

```
public async Task setUserEmail(string email)
{
string id = Context.ConnectionId;
CurrentConnections.Where(a => a.connection_id == id).FirstOrDefault().email = email;
}
```

you shold remove enties from CurrentConnections list `OnDisconnectedAsync`

```
public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
var connection = CurrentConnections.Where(a => a.connection_id == 
Context.ConnectionId).FirstOrDefault();

if (connection != null)
{
    CurrentConnections.Remove(connection);
}

return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}
```

after that you can send based on email address

Comment: How do you store this list?

Comment: You don't store this list it's online , It's a list of currently online users.

Comment: @WowoOt how to call setUserEmail method in my js file?

Comment: `await connection.invoke("setUserEmail ", email);`

Comment: @Wowo Ot I tried but Nothing happened, how can I use connection.invoke in my above js file and hub class

Comment: @WowoOt I tried but Nothing happened, how can I use connection.invoke in my above js file and hub class

Comment: Have tried to put it after start `connection.start().then(() => connection.invoke('setUserEmail ', email));`

Comment: @WowoOt I adapted to database with your code like above . I edited my problem in the above. Which codes are wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure , it should be working , try to put a break point on the server Hub `OnConnectedAsync` to see if there is actually a connection with the server !

Comment: Another thing you need to consider is to make sure that you have a valid `SSL` Certificate if your connection is over `https` , otherwise try it using regular `http`.