# How to share a message to specific client by using SignalR with ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to implement a small demo in sample chat application.

I'm using SignalR in an ASP.NET MVC5 application, but found some problem while sending a message to specific/single client.

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
        string connectionId = "";     

        public string GetConnectionId()
        {
            return connectionId;
        }
        
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;        
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
}

public class Common
{   
        public static void Send(string name, string message,string connectionId)
        {     
            IHubContext Context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();       
            Context.Clients.Client(connectionId).addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
        }           
}
```

I don't want to make following as static

```
public string GetConnectionId()
{
    return connectionId;
}
```

Then how can I send the `connectionId` to

```
Common.Send(name, message, connectionId)
```

which is being called in an ASP.NET MVC controller.

Is there any better suggestion/recommendation ?

Application built with ASP.NET MVC 5 with SignalR 2.4.1.

I am using this link for my demo application. You can see all details related to source code is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc

Output: I tried to follow guides and looked up example implementations but could not solve the issue.

Mostly people are saying you can't do it by using `GetHubContext`

See it

https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2274#issuecomment-389227033
https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2274#issuecomment-389013456
[Connection ID when calling SignalR Core Hub method from Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50367586/connection-id-when-calling-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller)

Comment: I would recommend using groups to join your users in to the "chatGroups" and send messages to the groups. You can see this github for example chat implementation with groups. https://github.com/Kiril1512/SignalRDemo/blob/master/Server/Hubs/SignalRHub.cs

Comment: OK I 'll check it and inform you asap