# How use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client Version 3 and up in xamarin.forms

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, signalr

I need to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` in xamarin forms project.
But I don't know how to use it for config hubconnetion and start my hub.

I use version 1.0.1, but this version not contain connectionId for send to special user and I need to use higher versions.

Please help me by example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version for the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client is 6.0.5, you could download it from below [url](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client).

Besides, for how to build the connection and start the hub, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

For about how to send the message to specific user, I suggest you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50367586/connection-id-when-calling-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio